# Sending Mail via SMTP on Japan ISP

Tags: php, smtp, gmail

I have this weird problem. I have setup my PHP app to send email to users, for now it is using gmail. There is no problem sending mail from my machine. But when my colleague in Japan tried my app, it doesn't send the mail. In the logs, it says that the app failed to authenticate.

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
        'smtp' => array(
            'host'  => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'port'  => 465,
            'username' => 'test.email@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'password',
            'timeout' => 5,
 ),
 'newline' => "\r\n"
```

He is running the app in his machine, not from a remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google might have blocked your login because it was deemed as suspicious. (https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6063333?hl=en)

You might want to login to this account and navigate to https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity and allow blocked device to continue.